# Excel extract all data of drop down list into Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have copied a drop down list cell from other sheet and trying to fetch its all items name. Dropdown list is created through excel property by [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/) link, not using **Combo Box**. Is there any way to get all items of drop down list ?
Means get the original list which is mapped to the drop down.

I tried to get it through VB Script also but it does not work.

```
Dim dd As DropDown
Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("MyDropDown")
```

When I debug that code it show "unable to get the dropdowns property of the worksheet class" error at

```
Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("MyDropDown")
```

line and this [Excel dropdowns in VBA: "Unable to get the DropDowns property of the Worksheet class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633829/excel-dropdowns-in-vba-unable-to-get-the-dropdowns-property-of-the-worksheet-c)
not helped me. 
Is **ActiveSheet.DropDowns("MyDropDown")** works only for Combo Box ?
Then how I get all items either using excel property or VB Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, your original question didn't make it clear that you were using Data Validation. To loop through all the items in a Data Validation list, you can use this code:

```
Sub loopthroughvalidationlist()
     Dim inputRange As Range
     Dim c As Range
     ' Change range below to first cell in your list
     Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("J6").Validation.Formula1)
     For Each c In inputRange
        MsgBox (c)
     Next c
End Sub
```