# Dealing with Dropdowns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I want my worksheet to interact with the user input through the dropdown. Basically I need to copy and paste columns of data according to the input via the dropdown button.

This is my code

```
Sub DropDown84_Change()


 If ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 84").Value = 1 Then
 Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("E48:B50").Value
 ElseIf ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 84").Value = 2 Then
 Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("F48:F50").Value
 ElseIf ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 84").Value = 3 Then
 Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("G48:G50").Value
 ElseIf ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 84").Value = 4 Then
 Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("H48:H50").Value
 Else: Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("J48:J50").Value

End If


End Sub
```

I receive a message

"Runtime error 1004, Unable to get the DropDowns property of the worksheet class"

Please help,

Comment: You get that error if one of the named dropdowns doesn't exist: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4633829/4996248

Comment: The named DropDown doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe you changed the Name of the DropDowns or the name is `"DropDown84"`. Anyways you should write this code using `Select Case`: `Select Case ActiveSheet.DropDown("DropDown84").Value`. If you want to use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Comment: @Kalokal why `Select Case`? `If..Elseif` works just as well.

Comment: @Kyle I know, but the `Select Case` method really helps to keep your code clean, look at the answer I posted below.

Comment: how do you find the name of the drop down?

Comment: @Kyle Activate the developer mode and right click on the ComboBox.

Comment: it shows "Drop Down 84" on the top left place where it shows the cell number

Comment: I no longer receive the error message and the code compiles perfectly, however, it does not work properly, The input from the DropDown84 changes but the data columns are not changed

Answer (score 0):

I hope you use ActiveX for this:

```
Sub ComboBox84_Change()

Select Case ActiveSheet.ComboBox84.Value
    Case 1
        Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("E48:B50").Value
    Case 2
        Sheets("data").Range("N28:N30").Value = Sheets("data").Range("F48:F50").Value
    Case 3
        '-- do for all of your cases--
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: the ComboBox84 is fixed or I can change it?

Comment: Yes, as long as you used ActiveX Combo boxes :)

Comment: I did not use an ActiveX drop box

Comment: Ok, have you tried left clicking on the ComboBox and looking up the name in the top right corner?

Comment: yeah it is Drop Down 18

Comment: I would also like to note that it seems to be working now
however, I need to click "Run Sub" in the VBA compiler to actually change anything. It does not automatically the data based on the input from the user instantly.

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Dropdowns("Dropdown 18").Value`. This gives me the selected value of the dropdown list.

Comment: The problem is, that you can't really asign code to the normal Dopdowns. You need the activeX ComboBox for that. Try exchanging a DropDown with a ActiveX ComboBox and then using the code from above. The only Problem is that you have to add the data with `ComboBox1.AddItem "something"`.